# PlainText (); puede ir vacio?

Tags: android-studio

Hola he estado viendo ejemplos de un *`Drag&Drop`* de android studio pero en un ejemplo que vi aparece esto:

```
View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData.newPlainText("","");
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(dragData, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Mi duda es que al pasarlo a Android, me marca un error al escribir el `plainText`.

Comment: Que error? Ambos parametros son Charsequence.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no se como usarlo, ya que el ejemplo el plain text aparece asi ("","") pero en android me marca un error diciendo que no tiene solucion a eso o que no se reconoce

Comment: ok agrega el paquete de la clase como muestro en la respuesta, por cierto, de donde tomaste este ejemplo?

Comment: Lo vi en Youtube porque estamos practicando de un canal que se llama iDeveloperPro o algo asi, porque no sabemos como hacer un drag en android, lo hicimos en swing con labels

Answer (score 0):

Los parametros de `ClipData.newPlainText()` son el titulo y el texto que quieres sea guardado en el portapapeles, ejemplo:

```
new ClipData.newPlainText("PlainText puede ir vacio?","Hola he estado viendo ejemplos de un drag & drop de android studio pero en un ejemplo que vi aparece esto:");
```

En cuanto a que no reconoce el método, tienes que agregar el paquete de la clase :

```
android.content.ClipData dragData = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("","");
```